# Errors arising from simultaneous use of Screen.ActiveForm and DoCmd.Close

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public frmPrevious as Form

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm
End Sub

Private Sub SvExitBtn_Click()
    If frmPrevious.Name = "LocationFrm" Then
        .......
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "AddressEntry", acSaveYes
    Else
        .......
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "AddressEntry", acSaveYes

    End If

End Sub
```

So I'm using `Screen.ActiveForm` on the Load event so that I can trick Access into setting the prior form to the variable `frmPrevious`. This way I can detect which forms the user navigated *from* and run a specific block of code to account for that.

Essentially what's happening is the user searches for an address from a pre-defined list. If they can't find it from those search results, they open a new form `AddressEntry` and key in the new address. Once finished they click the `SvExitBtn` which should save the record and close *only* that form.

Unfortunately the button is also closing the form set to `frmPrevious`. I'm assuming this is because `DoCmd.Close` closes the active window, but that's why I set the additional parameters. So I'm not understanding why this isn't working?

Comment: Does `Debug.Assert Not frmPrevious Is Me` break if you add it just underneath the `frmPrevious` assignment in `Form_Load`? (or `Debug.Assert Not Screen.ActiveForm Is Me` *before* the `frmPrevious` assignment)

Comment: Nothing broke after using both statements

Comment: lol, I mean "break" as in "breakpoint" - `Debug.Assert` is essentially a conditional breakpoint, if the assertion is false, execution breaks (stops) right there, highlighting the assert call. If it would have stopped there it would have meant `Me` (i.e. that form) is *already* the active form when that assignment is made ;-) good to know that's not the case. Does `Me` have a member that looks anything like a `Close` method? e.g. `Me.Close` instead of `DoCmd`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The only `Me` line(s) are `Me.SvExitBtn.Enabled = False` and `Me.SvExitBtn.Enabled = True` on Load and Dirty of a particular ctl.

Comment: I mean can't you do `Me.Close` instead of `DoCmd.Close`?

Comment: `DoCmd.Close acForm, "AddressEntry"` will only close the form with the name "AddressEntry". If another form is closed too, that code must be elsewhere - e.g. where you opened "AddressEntry"? -- The generic way to close the form a button is on: `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Access forms don't have a `.Close` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do any of that. When the user opens form AddressEntry, make it open in `dialog` mode. When it is closed you will return to the starting form. Done.